# Let $K$ be a local field of positive character. Why can we say completion of ${\overline{K}}$ is separably closed?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $K$ be a local field of positive character.
Why can we say completion of ${\overline{K}}$ is separably closed ?

I think I need to use Krasner's lemma.
Suppose $α$ be algebraic separable element overcompletion of ${\overline{K}}$.
Let $f(x)$ be minimal polynomial of $α$.
I want to find some irreducible polynomial $g∈ \overline{K}[x]$ whose degree is equal to $f$.
Then, $deg f＝1$ and we gain the result.

How can I find such $g$ by Krasner lemma?

P.S  I'm asking how to apply Krasner's lemma

Answer (score 1):

With $L$ your completion,

You need the general version of Hensel lemma,

The one assuming that $f\in O_{L}[x]$ monic has a root $a$ in $O_{L}/(b)$ and  that $v(b),v(f(a))$ are large enough compared to $v(f'(a))$. Then the algorithm lifting $a$ to a root $A\in O_{L}$ is the one you know, $a_0=a,a_{n+1}= a_n-f(a_n)/f'(a_n),A=\lim_n a_n$.